Can we extend the committing security notion to stream cipher?
Can we consider a stream cipher, which takes a key $K$ and a initial vector $IV$ and generates a keystream. Is it possible to construct an attack similar to the notion of context-committing attack, which the adversary can give different ($K_1,IV_1$) and ($K_2,IV_2$), they can both produce the same keystream?

That depends on the stream cipher, the required output sizes, etc. For large outputs of a secure ( = we don't know they are weak) stream cipher, the answer is obviously, no. Just model the output as coin tossing and see the probability...

I guess the question is 1. are these notion even applicable to stream ciphers and if yes 2. in which specific circumstances.

As far as I know, the notions have only been discussed in the context of AEADs and MACs. However, the padding fix is an example of this not being a problem for secure stream ciphers. It's been analysed by multiple papers.

Having said that, I contacted some cryptographers about using HChaCha20 over the AEAD tag for key commitment, and they didn't think it would be key committing. The idea was to use the a key derived from the ChaCha20-Poly1305 keystream as the HChaCha20 key and the tag as the HChaCha20 nonce. Then Bernstein has said the Salsa20 core isn't collision resistant and made Rumba20 for collision resistance. It gets very confusing to reason about.
